# How can i read this formatted text file with c?

Tags: c, file-io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLP3L.png)

i have text file of movies and actors.But last actor names are connected to next movies name as you see and i have no idea how to read this file,can you help me about it?

Note:edit isnt allowed

Comment: At least, post a link to the `input-bacon.txt` file at Princeton. I did a web search on several of the names and got: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwj02LrXlrnpAhXbmnIEHY6MBv4QFjABegQIAxAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.cs.princeton.edu%2Fpub%2Fcs226%2Fbacon%2Finput-bacon.txt&usg=AOvVaw0aM2BJdwp4G_TYkEwanFfS In that file, the films are each separated by a **newline**

Answer (score 0):

As I've noticed, the name of the actor is attached to the name of the movie in such away that there is no space before the movie. So you can search for combination of a non-space and non-slash character followed by the upper-case letter. For example search for upper-case letters and when you find one, check if the previous character is a lower-case letter. If that is the case, the movie starts at this point.